# Terminology: interior subunits of polytope compounds

Tags: geometry, terminology

Edit: trying a better time of day.

I'm trying to learn some geometry on my own and am getting drowned in terminology.

The structures I'm looking to identify are those created by the overlap of two or more polytopes.

A 2-dimensional example would be the subunits of a [hexagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Star_polygon_6-2.svg) composed as a compound of two equilateral triangles. There are 7 subunits, or alternatively 6 plus a hexagon core.

A 3-dimensional example would be the subunits of the [stella octangula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Compound_of_two_tetrahedra.png) composed as a compound of two tetrahedra. There are 9 subunits, or 8 plus an octahedron core.

Do these have a particular name?

More generally, I'd like to find out what determines the maximum number of such subunits for a compound of two like polygons/polyhedra. Why is 7 the maximum for two triangles, 9 the maximum for two tetrahedra, and so on?